# Number of queued tasks; how can I avoid a global variable?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am writing a minimalist code based on asyncio and composed of tasks, workers and a queue:

- Workers look in the queue for a task and execute it
- Tasks are represented as a random asyncio.sleep()
- When a task is done it adds two more tasks to the queue

Two restrictions:

- 10 max worker at a time
- 100 tasks should be executed in total, the script should end then

To monitor the total number of tasks executed, I use a global variable task_queued updated each time a task is being added to the queue.

I'm sure there's a better, pythonic way, to do that and not using a global variable, but all the solution I came up with are much more complicated.

I'm missing something here, any clue ?

Here's my code:

```
import asyncio
from random import random
import sys

MAX_WORKERS = 10
MAX_TASKS = 100

task_queued = 0

async def task(queue, id="1"):
    global task_queued
    sleep_time = 0.5 + random()
    print('     Begin task #{}'.format(id))
    await asyncio.sleep(sleep_time)
    if task_queued < MAX_TASKS:
        await queue.put(id + ".1")
        task_queued += 1
    if task_queued < MAX_TASKS:
        await queue.put(id + ".2")
        task_queued += 1
    print('     End task #{} ({} item(s) in the queue)'.format(id, queue.qsize()))


async def worker(worker_id, queue):
    while True:
        task_id = await queue.get()
        print('Worker #{} takes charge of task {}'.format(worker_id, task_id))
        await task(queue, task_id)
        queue.task_done()


async def main():
    global task_queued
    print('Begin main \n')
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    await queue.put("1") # We add one task to the queue
    task_queued += 1

    workers = [asyncio.create_task((worker(worker_id + 1, queue))) for worker_id in range(MAX_WORKERS)]

    await queue.join()

    print('Queue is empty, {} tasks completed'.format(task_queued))
    for w in workers:
        w.cancel()

    print('\n End main')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(main())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('\nBye bye')
        sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: You can use a class, and make your functions methods of the class. All the methods will then automatically receive `self`, and you can replace the global variable `task_queued` with an instance member `self.task_queued`. You would initialize the variable in the constructor (`__init__`). This classic OO approach allows the methods to share the state without confining it to a singleton - e.g. it then becomes possible to run two queues at the same time.

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick

Answer (score 1):

Thank to user4815162342 for the answer, here's the code if anyone is interested

```
import asyncio
from random import random
import sys


class Factory:
    """
    Factory
    """

    def __init__(self, max_workers, max_tasks):
        self.task_queued = 0
        self.max_workers = max_workers
        self.max_tasks = max_tasks

        self.queue = asyncio.Queue()

    async def task(self, task_id):
        sleep_time = 0.5 + random()
        print('     Begin task #{}'.format(task_id))
        await asyncio.sleep(sleep_time)

        if self.task_queued < self.max_tasks:
            await self.queue.put(task_id + ".1")
            self.task_queued += 1
        if self.task_queued < self.max_tasks:
            await self.queue.put(task_id + ".2")
            self.task_queued += 1

        print('     End task #{} ({} item(s) in the queue)'.format(task_id, self.queue.qsize()))


    async def worker(self, worker_id):
        while True:
            task_id = await self.queue.get()
            print('Worker #{} takes charge of task {}'.format(worker_id, task_id))
            await self.task(task_id)
            self.queue.task_done()


    async def organize_work(self):
        print('Begin work \n')

        await self.queue.put("1") # We add one task to the queue to start
        self.task_queued += 1

        workers = [asyncio.create_task((self.worker(worker_id + 1))) for worker_id in range(self.max_workers)]

        await self.queue.join()

        print('Queue is empty, {} tasks completed'.format(self.task_queued))
        for w in workers:
            w.cancel()
        print('\nEnd work')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    factory = Factory(max_workers=3, max_tasks=50)

    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(factory.organize_work())

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('\nBye bye')
        sys.exit(0)
```